# How to get all dates between two date time pickers

Tags: c#, date, datetimepicker

I have two date time pickers called dtpStartDate and dtpEndDate. When a user select dates for dtpStartDate and dtpEndDate, I want to get all working dates between those two date time picker values.

eg :- If the user selected dtpStartDate as "30-01-2014" and dtpEndDate as "05-02-2014" output result should be

```
30-01-2014   //(Thursday)    

31-01-2014   //(Friday) 

03-02-2014   //(Monday) 

04-02-2014   //(Tuesday)

05-02-2014   //(WednesDay)
```

(01-02-2014 and 02-02-2014 should not belongs to the output since those days are holidays.)

please somebody give me a correct code for accomplish that task. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you'd show what you've tried so far. It's a pretty simple `for` loop (if you can detect days you want to skip easily)...

Comment: And what about national holidays? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1199133/3239917

Comment: @Steve Doesn't need to consider national holidays here.

Comment: @JonSkeet > I'm little bit new to C#. I know I have to use an array to store dates. but I dont have an idea to do the remaining things

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri: It's not clear why you need an array at all. I'd just use a `for` loop with an iteration variable which starts off as the start date, continues as long as it's less than or equal to the end date, and uses `date = date.AddDays(1)` as the iteration step. Then in the loop, just check whether the day of the week is Saturday or Sunday...

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly achieve this like:

```
var startDate= dtpStartDate.Date;
var endDate= dtpEndDate.Date;
List<DateTime> workingDays= new List<DateTime>();

for(DateTime counter= startDate; counter<= endDate; counter=counter.AddDays(1))
{
if(counter.DayOfWeek !=DayOfWeek.Saturday && counter.DayOfWeek!=DayOfWeek.Sunday)
   workingDays.Add(counter);
}

// Here you can use the list of working days.
```

Comment: I don't have VS on this machine. So wrote Code directly here.. Anyways thanks for pointing Konrad.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a solution with Linq. It works, but I am not sure if there is a better way.

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2014,1,30);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2014,2,5);
int totalDays = (int)(d2 - d1).TotalDays;
List<DateTime> dateStart = new List<DateTime>(){d1};

var result = dateStart.SelectMany(d => Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
                      .Select(days => d.AddDays(days))
                      .Where(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && 
                                  x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday));
```