# How to select the dates depending on the number

Tags: c#, datetime

The user has a subscription, for example, for 12 lessons per month.  On Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays.  How to calculate when the subscription ends and enter the dates in the database when a person will have training.  That is, this is not one end date of the subscription, this is a set of dates on which days a person will have training in the gym.  In this case, you can specify different days on which there will be training and their count.  For example, 6 workouts on Mondays and Wednesdays will end on 01/18/2023 if counting from today.  And the dates you need to get are 01/02/2023, 01/04/2023, 01/09/2023, 01/11/2023 and so on

I don't know how to implement it

Comment: you mean, store the dates for Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays at those 12 months? - if not, please, [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Store the dates when the client will have classes. If these are 12 classes that start from today, then the dates we need are 01/02/2023, 01/03/2023, 01/04/2023, 01/09/2023, 01/10/2023, 01/11/2023, 01/16/2023 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [loop the days between the date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199121/12511801) and then check if the day is (*Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays*); if so, you have the dates you want.

Code sample:

```
// Start and end dates = in your case, 12 months.
DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(12);
// Loop the days between the start and end dates: 
for (DateTime counter = start; counter <= end; counter = counter.AddDays(1))
{
    // Handle the days (i.e. Monday, Tuesday, etc) : 
    switch (counter.DayOfWeek)
    {
        // If the day matches your criteria: 
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            // Here is where you get the date and store it in your database: 
            Console.WriteLine("Day: " + counter.DayOfWeek.ToString() + " -- Date: " + counter.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Day: Monday -- Date: 01/02/2023
Day: Tuesday -- Date: 01/03/2023
Day: Wednesday -- Date: 01/04/2023
Day: Monday -- Date: 01/09/2023
Day: Tuesday -- Date: 01/10/2023
Day: Wednesday -- Date: 01/11/2023
Day: Monday -- Date: 01/16/2023
[and so on - depending of the date ranges]
```

[dotnetfiddle.net sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z03qMl) and the [preview](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Preview?url=/Widget/z03qMl).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the 4th Wednesday based on the given DateTime.

In this case, I have used the current DateTime. but you can pass the DateTime accordingly or you can modify this method based on your requirement.

```
private static DateTime GetFourthWednesday(DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 4)
    {
        if (firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 4)
        {
            return firstDayOfMonth;
        }

        firstDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(1);

    }

    return firstDayOfMonth;
}

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var dt = GetFourthWednesday(now);
```

Comment: I have corrected the description of the question, please have a look

Comment: your question is really very unclear now after the new modification. by what logic it will end on 01/18/2023 ?

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate dates by using `DateTime.Now.AddDays(DaysInNumber)` or `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(MonthInNumber)` etc. in C#.

Comment: yes, but it will only return the subscription end date to me. but i have to get all the days the client has training